# What, exactly, is the system linux API?

Tags: linux, api, linux-kernel, kernel

I have this question and I don't know if the answer is true or false : the system API represents all the internal functions of the linux kernel? true or false? Thanks in advance everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the system API represents the external interface of the Linux kernel. API stands for Application Program (or Programming) Interface.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much !